# How do I summarise() correctly in R? [specific case]

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table with respondents and their answers on the survey and companies they belong to. I want to know how many respondents answered the question by each company.

Data:

```
structure(list(respondent = c("a", "a", "a2", "a", "b", "b", 
"c", "c", "c", "d", "d3", "d", "d", "d2", "d", "e", "e", "e", 
"f", "g"), question = c("q1", "q2", "q1", "q2", "q1", "q2", "q1", 
"q2", "q1", "q2", "q1", "q2", "q1", "q2", "q1", "q2", "q1", "q2", 
"q1", "q2"), answer = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 
0, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1), name = c("AU", "AU", "GU", "AU", 
"AU", "AU", "BU", "BU", "CU", "DU", "BU", "DU", "DU", "EU", "DU", 
"EU", "EU", "EU", "FU", "GU")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

You see, I try to use `tidyverse` functions, to be more precise, `summarise()`. I write the followin code:

```
a <- dat %>%
  group_by(respondent, name) %>%
  summarise(q = n())
```

But the output is not something I really need. I want to recieve the dataframe where there's a column with `name` and another column with the number of unique respondents who attributed to this name in the original dataset. I realize that is something is wrong with my `summarise`, but I can't find the clue.

I want to get something like that

```
name    N
AU      2
BU      2
CU      1
DU      1
EU      1
GU      2
```

Comment: Look at `dplyr::n_distinct`, such as `n_distinct(respondent)`

Comment: @camille I think not at all

Comment: are you sure? There are 11 answers there, and I've tried out at least 4 of them that get exactly the output you're asking for, including variations on the answer you've accepted. Is there something else going on that's not in your question maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this for unique number of respondents

```
a <- dat %>%
     group_by( name) %>%
     summarise(q = length(unique(respondent)))
```

Comment: Eureka! Thank you, seems like it will help me!

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(n_resp = n_distinct(respondent))
#   name  n_resp
#   <chr>  <int>
# 1 AU         2
# 2 BU         2
# 3 CU         1
# 4 DU         1
# 5 EU         2
# 6 FU         1
# 7 GU         2
```

Or more concisely:

```
aggregate(respondent ~ name, df, n_distinct)
```